# How to represent a type that belongs to multiple other types in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a model in which many things can have addresses. For the sake of this example lets assume that people can have multiple addresses and companies can also have multiple addresses. If two people share the same address, I want to create separate address records for them, so each address belongs to exactly one person or one company.

I can define some tables like this (abbreviated):

```js
var Person = sequelize.define('Person', {})
var Company = sequelize.define('Company', {})
var Address = sequelize.define('Address', {})
```

But when it comes to `hasMany()` and `belongsToMany()` calls I get a bit stuck. Clearly a person has many addresses but an address can belong to one person or one company.

`Person` can't have an `AddressId` because a person can have many addresses, and `Address` can't have `PersonId` because the address might be for a `Company` or some other type. This leads me to think that I should use `belongsToMany()` with a through table, but the relationship between `Person` and `Address` is not many-many; the same address (in my model) can not be associated with multiple people.

What is the right way to represent this in Sequelize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to represent this in Sequelize is to use a polymorphic association, which allows you to associate an address with either a person or a company using the same foreign key.

For example, you can use this code:

```
var Person = sequelize.define("Person", {});
var Company = sequelize.define("Company", {});
var Address = sequelize.define("Address", {
  // ...
  addressableType: Sequelize.STRING,
});

Person.hasMany(Address, {
  foreignKey: "addressableId",
  constraints: false,
  scope: {
    addressableType: "Person",
  },
});

Company.hasMany(Address, {
  foreignKey: "addressableId",
  constraints: false,
  scope: {
    addressableType: "Company",
  },
});

Address.belongsTo(Person, {
  foreignKey: "addressableId",
  constraints: false,
  as: {
    singular: "personAddress",
    plural: "personAddresses",
  },
});

Address.belongsTo(Company, {
  foreignKey: "addressableId",
  constraints: false,
  as: {
    singular: "companyAddress",
    plural: "companyAddresses",
  },
});


const address = await Address.findOne({ where: { id: 1 } });
const person = await address.getPersonAddress();
const company = await address.getCompanyAddress();
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. This looks like it will do what I want.

Comment: This compiles OK, but I get a runtime error "You have used the alias addressable in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases."

Comment: According to the Sequelize documentation, you need to use unique aliases for each association. - I updated my answer. Please test my code.